# Activate window from taskbar

Tags: delphi, taskbar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you make a Borderless Application Main Window in Windows, without WS_POPUP style?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4901965/can-you-make-a-borderless-application-main-window-in-windows-without-ws-popup-st)

I have a form with BorderStyle:=bsNone;

How can I activate the minimized form by clicking on a it in task bar?

Comment: This *is* a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4901965/can-you-make-a-borderless-application-main-window-in-windows-without-ws-popup-st, even if the title of this question might not be the best.

Comment: You only need to include the `WS_MINIMIZEBOX` window style. But I won't post this as an example, for that wouldn't be right against David that first discovered that in the first question about this.

Comment: @Andreas, @CloseVoters - This question has no constraint for excluding the `WS_POPUP` style, which is the entire point of the other question.

Comment: @Sertac: Well, the problem is the same (how to make the taskbar work with a borderless form) and the answer is the same (include the `WS_MINIMIZEBOX` window style). That sounds similar enough for me. Of course, I could very easily write an answer to this question, but that would feel like stealing David's answer to the old question.

Comment: @Sertac: I think that the `WS_POPUP` part of the old question was merely an unintentional red herring (is there a better word for this?). The OP just thought the problem was related to that window style. His actual problem was exactly the same as in this question, namely, if the form is borderless, then Win+M, the taskbar etc. stop working.

Comment: @Andreas - The restoring part seems to work without `WS_MINIMIZEBOX`, like Cosmin, I see no problem with D2007. But I guess there's a good probability that other points (Win+M etc..) will follow and you'll turn out to be correct..

Comment: The first thing you notice when you have `bsNone` as `BorderStyle`, is that the window isn't minimized when you click the taskbar button (in Windows 7, at least). Also, Win+M doesn't work. I think that the former is what the OP is really after.

Comment: @Andreas - A lot of guessing... Voted to close on the ground of being ambiguous..

Answer (score 4):

I'm guessing you're using an older version of Delphi (I've just done my testing on Delphi 2010, and I'm guessing you're using something older because in my version I don't need to do anything, restoring the window just works).

**Problem 1**: How do you MINIMIZE a border-less form? A border-less form doesn't have an "minimize" button! Are you sure it's minimized and it's not actually hidden? I've just attempted this, and I was only able to minimize the form by placing a button on it and running this code from the button:

```
ShowWindow(Handle, SW_MINIMIZE);
```

If I clicked on the application's button in my Windows 7 taskbar it came right up without problem. This brings us to the second problem.

**Problem 2**: What version of Delphi are you using? What version of Windows? Unfortunately it matters. There were changes in what Windows did with the taskbar button, and those changes prompted more changes in what Delphi does to support the taskbar button.

If you're on some old version of Delphi and on some new version of Windows you might try dropping a `TApplicationEvents` on your form, and from it's `OnRestore` event do this:

```
ShowWindow(Handle, SW_SHOW or SW_RESTORE);
```

Comment: It doesn't need to be very old. Delphi 2009 displays this problem. Anyhow, this question is a duplicate.

Comment: A more VCL way to minimize is to set [`WindowState`](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/Forms_TCustomForm_WindowState.html), which calls `ShowWindow` after checking state etc..

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to do

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
  private
  protected
    procedure CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams); override;
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;
```

where

```
procedure TForm1.CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams);
begin
  inherited;
  Params.Style := Params.Style or WS_MINIMIZEBOX;
end;
```

exactly as David did [in the old question about this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4901965/can-you-make-a-borderless-application-main-window-in-windows-without-ws-popup-st).

Comment: That didn't work for me in Win7.  It had weird side effects.

Comment: @Warren P: Still you did accept David's answer? Could you describe the side effects?

Comment: The taskbar malfunctions in Windows 7, with this.