# Smooth resizing in a borderless form/window in Delphi

Tags: forms, delphi, resize, smoothing, borderless

I am trying to resize a borderless form but when I increase the size using the right/bottom side, I get a gap between the border and the old client area that depends of the speed you move the mouse.

The effect is more noticeable when you resize from the left border or even from the bottomleft corner, it's horrible everywhere (I tried with other commercial apps and it happens as well). This effect happens as well when I change to sizable border, but it's not as awful as when I remove form borders

The form layout consists in a top panel doing the title bar function (with some tImages and buttons), and some other panels showing other info (like a memo, other controls, etc)

There's a snip of my code where I capture the mouse button and send a message to windows, but I also tried to do it manually with the similar results

Activating the double buffer for the top panel avoids flickering, but resizing the panel is not synchronized with form resizing, thus appearing a gap, or part of the panel disapearing

```
 procedure TOutputForm.ApplicationEvents1Message( var Msg: tagMSG;
  var Handled: Boolean );
const
  BorderBuffer = 5;
var
  X, Y: Integer;
  ClientPoint: TPoint;
  direction: integer;
begin
  Handled := false;
  case Msg.message of
    WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
      begin
        if fResizable then
        begin
          if fSides = [sTop] then
            direction := 3
          else if fSides = [sLeft] then
            direction := 1
          else if fSides = [sBottom] then
            direction := 6
          else if fSides = [sRight] then
            direction := 2
          else if fSides = [sRight, sTop] then
            direction := 5
          else if fSides = [sLeft, sTop] then
            direction := 4
          else if fSides = [sLeft, sBottom] then
            direction := 7
          else if fSides = [sRight, sBottom] then
            direction := 8;
          ReleaseCapture;
          SendMessage( Handle, WM_SYSCOMMAND, ( 61440 + direction ), 0 );
          Handled := true;
        end;
      end;
    WM_MOUSEMOVE:
      begin
        // Checks the borders and sets fResizable to true if it's in a "border" 
        // ...
      end; // mousemove
  end; // case
end;
```

How could I avoid that area and/or force windows to be redrawn? I am using Delphi but a generic solution (or in other language) or even a direction to go forward would be fine for me

Thank you in advance

Comment: You mean that there is "gap" during the resize, once you end the resize operation the form is painted OK?

Comment: How do you resize the borderless form?

Comment: But more important: do you paint yourself? Do you use the OnPaint eventhandler? If all so: maybe the painting is too heavy or could the painting be done smarter? Please show us your code design, then we can help you better.

Comment: You cannot resize a borderless form the way your describe. (by dragging on the resize border). How about you tell us what you are really doing and show us some code.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, were busy days here. I did it using wm_syscommand and also setting bounds manually capturing the wm_mousemove message, but the result is the same, it takes a lot of time between the mouse moves until the window is repainted, I suppose it's the normal windows behavior cos almost all the programs I use does it, but I would like to know how to minimize it or even avoid if it's possible.

Comment: @NGLN: I don't paint anything at all, it's just a demo app to try borderless resize and so and there's only Delphi standard controls, but what I realized is that the more controls they are, the slower it paints, as you point in it's second comment.

Comment: The only way I am able to reproduce the effect your describing is to put a `Sleep(250)` into the OnResize event handler. Show us your resize code.

Comment: What part of code do you need?

Comment: I updated the post with some code and more blablabla

Comment: BTW, you can use `SC_SIZE` and `WMSZ_LEFT`, `WMSZ_RIGHT`, ... constants..

Comment: @Sertac Akyuz thank you for the advice of the constants, after what I read before and after posting is that the less you draw in the form, the less it will flicker at all. I suppose I will have to disable updating some heavy controls before resizing, in order to let the interface to update as fast as possible. I have several solutions to try and a lot I had to discard.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Last time I attempted to manually make a top level window that resizes via WM_SYSCOMMAND and mouse drag, whether involving any nested panels or no, I found the problems were not limited only to flicker.

Even with a bare-TForm without a resizeable border, adding my own resizeable border and handling the mouse down and mouse move and mouse up messages directly proved too problematic. I gave up on the code-approach you are showing here, and instead I found two workable approaches:

1. use an approach where I take over the painting of the non-client areas. This is what Google Chrome and many other fully-custom windows do.  You still have a nonclient area and it's up to you to paint it and handle the non-client and border paint.  In other words, it's not truly borderless, but it could all be a single color, if you wanted it to be.  Read this [help about WM_NCPAINT messages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145212%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), to get started.
2. Use a borderless resizeable window that still gets recognized (even without its nonclient area as a resizeable window. Think of a post-it-note-applet. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4901965/can-you-make-a-borderless-application-main-window-in-windows-without-ws-popup-st) is a question I asked a while ago, at the bottom of my question is a fully working demo that provides a smooth flicker free way to have a borderless resizeable window. The underlying technique for the answer was provided by David H.

Comment: In the thread you refer, the second answer using SetWindowRgn seems to be fine, except when you maximize the window... the space for the title bar appears as a transparent rect (the space is reserved but it's not in the region to be visualized). I tried to remove the title bar using SetWindowLong( Handle,
    GWL_STYLE,
    GetWindowLong( Handle, GWL_STYLE )
    and not WS_CAPTION );
  ClientHeight := Height; in the CreateForm method but was useless cos it stop working at all :S

Comment: I abandoned that one for the same reasons you mention.  In other words, become friends with WM_NCPAINT, or forget it! :-) And WM_NCPAINT only remains feasible if you never let your main window freeze. Otherwise default frame/border/nonclient painting will be visible to the user, ruining the look of your app.

Comment: Life saver! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Well, Warren P already pretty convincingly pointed you in another direction, but I'll try to answer your question. Or not really.

Your edit makes the question very clear now:

> *The effect is more noticeable when you resize from the left border or even from the bottomleft corner, it's horrible everywhere (I tried with other commercial apps and it happens as well). This effect happens as well when I change to sizeable border, but it's not as awful as when I remove the border.*

Not only other commercial applications, but also every OS window manifests this effect. Stretching the top of an Explorer window also "hides" and "expands" the status bar or bottom panel. I am pretty sure it cannot be defeated.

It may seem worse for a borderless form, but I think that is just optical deception.

If I had to take a guess at explaining this effect, then I would say that during the resize operation, the update of top and left takes precedence over that of width and height, which results in both not being updated an equal amount of times. Maybe it is graphics card related. Or maybe, ...hell what am I talking about? This is way out of my reach.

Though, I still can not reproduce it for resizing the right and/or bottom of the form. If the amount of controls or (the combination of) their align and anchor properties is a problem, then you could consider temporarily disabling align all together, but I am almost sure you do not want that either. Below is my test code, copied from the question, slightly changed and of course with Sertac's constants added:

```
function TForm1.ResizableAt(X, Y: Integer): Boolean;
const
  BorderBuffer = 5;
var
  R: TRect;
  C: TCursor;
begin
  SetRect(R, 0, 0, Width, Height);
  InflateRect(R, -BorderBuffer, -BorderBuffer);
  Result := not PtInRect(R, Point(X, Y));
  if Result then
  begin
    FSides := [];
    if X < R.Left then
      Include(FSides, sLeft)
    else if X > R.Right then
      Include(FSides, sRight);
    if Y < R.Top then
      Include(FSides, sTop)
    else if Y > R.Bottom then
      Include(FSides, sBottom);
  end;
end;

function TForm1.SidesToCursor: TCursor;
begin
  if (FSides = [sleft, sTop]) or (FSides = [sRight, sBottom]) then
    Result := crSizeNWSE
  else if (FSides = [sRight, sTop]) or (FSides = [sLeft, sBottom]) then
    Result := crSizeNESW
  else if (sLeft in FSides) or (sRight in FSides) then
    Result := crSizeWE
  else if (sTop in FSides) or (sBottom in FSides) then
    Result := crSizeNS
  else
    Result := crNone;
end;

procedure TForm1.ApplicationEventsMessage(var Msg: tagMSG;
  var Handled: Boolean);
var
  CommandType: WPARAM;
begin
  case Msg.message of
    WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
      if FResizable then
      begin
        CommandType := SC_SIZE;
        if sLeft in FSides then
          Inc(CommandType, WMSZ_LEFT)
        else if sRight in FSides then
          Inc(CommandType, WMSZ_RIGHT);
        if sTop in FSides then
          Inc(CommandType, WMSZ_TOP)
        else if sBottom in FSides then
          Inc(CommandType, WMSZ_BOTTOM);
        ReleaseCapture;
        DisableAlign;
        PostMessage(Handle, WM_SYSCOMMAND, CommandType, 0);
        Handled := True;
      end;
    WM_MOUSEMOVE:
      with ScreenToClient(Msg.pt) do
      begin
        FResizable := ResizableAt(X, Y);
        if FResizable then
          Screen.Cursor := SidesToCursor
        else
          Screen.Cursor := Cursor;
        if AlignDisabled then
          EnableAlign;
      end;
  end;
end;
```

Concerning your top aligned panel: try setting `Align = alCustom` and `Anchors = [akLeft, akTop, akRight]`, though the enhancement may depend on the panel having a different color from that of the form, or maybe on me being optical deceived. ;)

Comment: I will try both Warren and yours, among others, but I think like you, it's windows fault (or a feature :) Thank you to both, I will let you both know what I get :D

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the form to `DoubleBuffered := True`?

Comment: I tried but as far as I remember, it avoid the realign flickering but didn't help with the space between margin and client area. I must study this possibility further but I would prefer not to use it by the moment :D

Comment: So you admit your problems are not just flicker! :-)

Comment: @Warren OP's clientarea isn't repainted in the ClipRect. As far as I remember, I once have witnessed this, but I'm not able to reproduce.

Comment: @Warren P and @NGLN, for me it's easily reproducible when you resize from the left border fastly (more even noticeable if you use the bottom-left one), but no, it's not flickering in the panel, as I stated in the name of the post, it's that I don't get a smooth resize effect and get nothing in the area that's new while I am resizing (maybe until windows has finished repainting the previous update in progress). I have to try different aproachs to minimize those effects and also read the post you kindly adviced in the answer before

Answer (score -1):

I know this thread is fairly old, but it is one that people still struggle with.

The answer is simple, though. The problem is that trying to do resize stuff makes you want to use the form you are resizing as a reference. *Don't do that.*

Use another form.

Here is the complete source for a TForm that can help you. Make sure that this form has **BorderStyle = bsNone**. You probably also want to make sure it is not visible.

```
unit UResize;
{
  Copyright 2014 Michael Thomas Greer
  Distributed under the Boost Software License, Version 1.0
  (See accompanying file LICENSE.txt or copy
   at http://www.boost.org/LICENSE_1_0.txt )
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
interface
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms, Dialogs;

const
  ResizeMaskLeft   = $1;
  ResizeMaskTop    = $2;
  ResizeMaskWidth  = $4;
  ResizeMaskHeight = $8;

type
  TResizeForm = class( TForm )
    procedure FormMouseMove( Sender: TObject;      Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer );
    procedure FormMouseUp(   Sender: TObject;
                             Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer );
  private
    anchor_g: TRect;
    anchor_c: TPoint;
    form_ref: TForm;
    resize_m: cardinal;

  public
    procedure SetMouseDown( AForm: TForm; ResizeMask: cardinal );
  end;

var
  ResizeForm: TResizeForm;


//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
implementation
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

{$R *.DFM}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
procedure TResizeForm.SetMouseDown( AForm: TForm; ResizeMask: cardinal );
  begin
  anchor_g.Left   := AForm.Left;
  anchor_g.Top    := AForm.Top;
  anchor_g.Right  := AForm.Width;
  anchor_g.Bottom := AForm.Height;
  anchor_c        := Mouse.CursorPos;
  form_ref        := AForm;
  resize_m        := ResizeMask;
  SetCapture( Handle )
  end;

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
procedure TResizeForm.FormMouseMove(
  Sender: TObject;
  Shift:  TShiftState;
  X, Y:   Integer
  );
  var
    p: TPoint;
    r: TRect;
  begin
  if Assigned( form_ref ) and (ssLeft in Shift)
    then begin
         p := Mouse.CursorPos;
         Dec( p.x, anchor_c.x );
         Dec( p.y, anchor_c.y );

         r.Left   := form_ref.Left;
         r.Top    := form_ref.Top;
         r.Right  := form_ref.Width;
         r.Bottom := form_ref.Height;

         if (resize_m and ResizeMaskLeft)   <> 0 then begin r.Left   := anchor_g.Left   + p.x;  p.x := -p.x end;
         if (resize_m and ResizeMaskTop)    <> 0 then begin r.Top    := anchor_g.Top    + p.y;  p.y := -p.y end;
         if (resize_m and ResizeMaskWidth)  <> 0 then       r.Right  := anchor_g.Right  + p.x;
         if (resize_m and ResizeMaskHeight) <> 0 then       r.Bottom := anchor_g.Bottom + p.y;

         with r do form_ref.SetBounds( Left, Top, Right, Bottom )
         end
  end;

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
procedure TResizeForm.FormMouseUp(
  Sender: TObject;
  Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift:  TShiftState;
  X, Y:   Integer
  );
  begin
  ReleaseCapture;
  form_ref := nil
  end;

end.
```

Now any borderless form in your application can be smoothly resized by hooking into ResizeForm with a simple

```
ResizeForm.SetMouseDown( self, (sender as TComponent).Tag );
```

A good place to put that is in the MouseDown event of whatever component(s) you are using to track the edges of your borderless form(s). (Notice how the Tag property is used to indicate what edge of your form you wish to drag/resize).

Oh, and set your form to **DoubleBuffered = true** to get rid of any remaining flicker.

This is just a small happiness I can give to you.