# Delphi Avoiding the form with no borders being flicker from right and bottom margins when Resizing

Tags: delphi, resize, flicker

i have Finished my Work but i get this Flickering problem exactelly
 when i want Resizing my Form (wich has bsNone in BorderStyle Property) from left Margin
 or bottom Margin, please try this Example first (full code inside):
 
[My Example =>](https://yadi.sk/d/LcZ1dAi6jUQJn)

finally here is the code:

```
const
  // frame Width
  BORDER_WIDTH = 5;
  // Key performance indicators (top-left, top-right ...)
  EDGE_SIZE = 15;    
var
  Form1: TForm1;    
implementation    
{$R *.dfm} 
procedure TForm1.FormMouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X,
  Y: Integer);
var
  fRect: TRect;
  fPos: TPoint;
  fChangedCursor: Boolean;
begin
  // Change cursor when the mouse pointer is located on the edge    
  fChangedCursor := False;
  fPos := Point(X, Y);    
  // top margin
  fRect := Rect(EDGE_SIZE, 0, Width - EDGE_SIZE, BORDER_WIDTH);
  if PtInRect(fRect, fPos) then
  begin
    fChangedCursor := True;
    Cursor := crSizeNS;
    if ssLeft in Shift then
    begin
    // here the bottom Margin flickering
      ReleaseCapture;
      PerForm(WM_SysCommand, $F003, 0);
    end;
  end;    
  // right margin
  fRect := Rect(Width - BORDER_WIDTH, EDGE_SIZE, Width, Height - EDGE_SIZE);
  if PtInRect(fRect, fPos) then
  begin
    fChangedCursor := True;
    Cursor := crSizeWE;
    if ssLeft in Shift then
    begin
      ReleaseCapture;
      PerForm(WM_SysCommand, $F002, 0);
    end;
  end;    
  // Bottom margin
  fRect := Rect(EDGE_SIZE, Height - BORDER_WIDTH, Width - EDGE_SIZE,    Height);
  if PtInRect(fRect, fPos) then
  begin
    fChangedCursor := True;
    Cursor := crSizeNS;
    if ssLeft in Shift then
    begin
      ReleaseCapture;
      PerForm(WM_SysCommand, $F006, 0);
    end;
  end;    
  // left margin
  fRect := Rect(0, EDGE_SIZE, BORDER_WIDTH, Height - EDGE_SIZE);
  if PtInRect(fRect, fPos) then
  begin
    fChangedCursor := True;
    Cursor := crSizeWE;
    if ssLeft in Shift then
    begin
    // here the Right Margin flickering
      ReleaseCapture;
      PerForm(WM_SysCommand, $F001, 0);
    end;
  end;    
  // Top left corner
  fRect := Rect(0, 0, EDGE_SIZE, EDGE_SIZE);
  if PtInRect(fRect, fPos) then
  begin
    fChangedCursor := True;
    Cursor := crSizeNWSE;
    if ssLeft in Shift then
    begin
      // here the Both Margins flickering
      ReleaseCapture;
      PerForm(WM_SysCommand, $F004, 0);
    end;
  end;    
  // Top right corner
  fRect := Rect(Width - EDGE_SIZE, 0, Width, EDGE_SIZE);
  if PtInRect(fRect, fPos) then
  begin
    fChangedCursor := True;
    Cursor := crSizeNESW;
    if ssLeft in Shift then
    begin
      // here the both Margins flickering
      ReleaseCapture;
      PerForm(WM_SysCommand, $F005, 0);
    end;
  end;    
// Bottom right corner
  fRect := Rect(Width - EDGE_SIZE, Height - EDGE_SIZE, Width, Height);
  if PtInRect(fRect, fPos) then
  begin
    fChangedCursor := True;
    Cursor := crSizeNWSE;
    if ssLeft in Shift then
    begin
    // here the both Margins flickering a Little
      ReleaseCapture;
      PerForm(WM_SysCommand, $F008, 0);
    end;
  end;    
  // Bottom left corner
  fRect := Rect(0, Height - EDGE_SIZE, EDGE_SIZE, Height);
  if PtInRect(fRect, fPos) then
  begin
    fChangedCursor := True;
    Cursor := crSizeNESW;
    if ssLeft in Shift then
    begin
    // here the Right Margin flickering
      ReleaseCapture;
      PerForm(WM_SysCommand, $F007, 0);
    end;
  end;    
  // Standardcursor    
 if not fChangedCursor then
    Cursor := crDefault;
end;
```

Comment: Duplicate? See: [Smooth resizing in a borderless form/window in Delphi](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6652655/757830)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what is the cause of the flickering's you are experiencing but your code for detecting if the mouse is on edge is a bit flawed.

I believe main problem of your code is that your specified rectangles are overlapping each other.

So when the mouse cursor is placed on let's say `Top Left corner` the code for `Top border`, `Left border` and `Top Left` corner would execute.

This would then result in calling of `ReleaseCapture` and `PerForm(WM_SysCommand, ...)` three times in a row.

So my first suggestion would be to change your border detection code so that it prevents code for multiple individual borders to be called at the same time.

Here is simplified example of border detection code that I'm using in one of my projects:

```
procedure TForm1.FormMouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X,
  Y: Integer);
var LeftEdge,RightEdge,TopEdge,BottomEdge: Boolean;
    BorderPosition: TBorderPos;
    BorderWidth: Integer;
begin
  BorderWidth := 20;
  LeftEdge := False;
  RightEdge := False;
  TopEdge := False;
  BottomEdge := False;
  //Check if mouse cursor is on left or right edge
  if X < BorderWidth then
  begin
    LeftEdge := True;
  end
  else if X > Self.Width-BorderWidth then
  begin
    RightEdge := True;
  end;

  //Check if mouse cursor is on top or bottom edge
  if Y < BorderWidth then
  begin
    TopEdge := True;
  end
  else if Y > Self.Height-BorderWidth then
  begin
    BottomEdge := True;
  end;

  //Get border position by using if..else if..else clause in order for if block
  //to break as soon as one of the conditions is met
  //First check for corners
  if TopEdge and LeftEdge then BorderPosition := bpTopLeft
  else if TopEdge and RightEdge then BorderPosition := bpTopRight
  else if BottomEdge and LeftEdge then BorderPosition := bpBottomLeft
  else if BottomEdge and RightEdge then BorderPosition := bpBottomRight
  //and only then check for individual edges
  else if TopEdge then BorderPosition := bpTop
  else if BottomEdge then BorderPosition := bpBottom
  else if LeftEdge then BorderPosition := bpLeft
  else if RightEdge then BorderPosition := bpRight
  //mouse cursor is not on any border edge
  else BorderPosition := bpNone;

  //Finally you can use case statement to execute needed code based on which
  //border edge is your mouse cursor positioned
  case BorderPosition of
    bpNone: Label1.Caption := 'Not on border';
    bpLeft: Label1.Caption := 'Left border';
    bpRight: Label1.Caption := 'Right border';
    bpTop: Label1.Caption := 'Top border';
    bpBottom: Label1.Caption := 'Bottom border';
    bpTopLeft: Label1.Caption := 'Top Left corner';
    bpTopRight: Label1.Caption := 'Top Right corner';
    bpBottomLeft: Label1.Caption := 'Bottom Left corner';
    bpBottomRight: Label1.Caption := 'Bottom Right corner';
  end;
end;
```

If needed you can even replace current BorderWidth variable with four variables (each for its own edge).

If nothing else my code should provide you with a bit better performance since it avoids checking point position against rectangle eight times as your code does.

Comment: thank's a lot for this example, but could you post a full One plz .. i want to try it as your original does .

Comment: @Bravesaw I'm afraid I can't do that since my original code also depends on a third party library (graphics engine) for rendering window content using either DirectX or OpenGL frameworks.