# Alt + Space is not working on a borderless window

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, borderless

I have created a borderless window by intercepting the `WM_NCCALCSIZE` command. The idea is to create a custom GUI. Here is the code that I used to create a clean slate:

```
case WM_NCCALCSIZE:
     return 0;
```

Somehow though, `WM_NCCALCSIZE` also disabled the system menu. Pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> only gives an error beep. I am unable to test the "Minimize" and "Maximize" functions. How can I restore the system menu?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can you make a Borderless Application Main Window in Windows, without WS\_POPUP style?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4901965/can-you-make-a-borderless-application-main-window-in-windows-without-ws-popup-s)

Comment: @anachronon - That's the not the way to create a borderless window.  Either create a window with the WS_POPUP style or with no style flags set.

Comment: That's the irony.  I have already tried both using both the `WS_POPUP` style, and `NULL` as a style.  Both proved to be dead-ends.

Comment: Here is another irony:  While playing with the windows styles, I found that using the `WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW` style (with the `WM_NCCALCSIZE` method above) gives me access to all functionality, without showing it.  I know---it seems rather counter-intuitive.

Comment: When I only use `WS_POPUP style`, the window will not be displayed, but `ALT+SPACE` can be used. However, there is no style included in the style, so I cannot click to maximize or minimize (the button is disabled). Could you provide more code snippets to help us reproduce the problem.